# ThreeJS linedistances after resize

Tags: three.js

I am trying to scale an object with dashed lines, but want the dash distances to stay the same.

[Orange Box should have proper dash distances](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CZDZ.jpg)

```
var geometryCube = cube(3);
geometryCube.computeLineDistances();
var object = new THREE.LineSegments(geometryCube, new THREE.LineDashedMaterial({ color: 0xffaa00, dashSize: 3, gapSize: 1, linewidth: 2 }));
object.scale.multiplyScalar(10);
geometryCube.computeLineDistances();
self.bbox.geometry.lineDistancesNeedUpdate = true;
self.scene.add(object);
```

neither `geometryCube.computeLineDistances();` helps nor `self.bbox.geometry.lineDistancesNeedUpdate = true;`.

Comment: does dashsize: .3 not work?  Or dashsize:30 gapsize:20  etc

Comment: Yes! Nice, it works by dividing by the scale factor. not pretty, but works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does dashsize: .3 not work? or dashsize: 30 gapsize: 20 etc?